# Uploading a Photo in React Native to a Node Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, multipartform-data

Attempting to upload a local asset (simple jpeg file) using a React library called, 'react-native-fetch-blob.' My server is logging the request, however no matter what I seem to try, the req.body is either empty or undefined.

I've attempted uploading the file as a 'base64' encoded string, still no luck.

I also know that my uri is valid.

Frontend code:

```
 RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/api/analyze', {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }, RNFetchBlob.wrap(this.state.imgSource.uri))
    .then( res => {
      console.log('success:', res);
    })
    .catch( err => {
      console.log('error:', err);
    })
```

I'm using express on the backend along with the express-formidable package for parsing multipart/form-data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've also spent a lot of time in the issues tracker for each of the packages I'm using, can't seem to find whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use native `fetch` API and `FormData` object. Something like that:

```
  const postImage = (imagePath) => {
    const photo = {
      uri: imagePath,
      name: 'image.jpg',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
    };
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', photo);
    const config = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    };
    return fetch("https://your.endpoint/img", config);
  }

  postImage(pathToYourFile)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

That way React Native knows how to convert given path into multipart request.

Comment: Hey thanks homie! That's a really clean response, I really appreciate that. I ended up using the library's native implementation of fetch. Essentially I had to do what you've done here, structure is a bit different. Thanks again! Learned a lot about MIME types.

Comment: @N.Pisciotti Glad I could help :) Please accept answer as correct if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: What if the file extension is dynamic? Like when using react-native-document picker where you can select many file types.